# Смена viewport при position: fixed в IE11?

Tags: html, css

Есть контейнер и в нем элемент

```
.journal{

            height: 300px;
            width: 600px;
            transform: rotateZ(0);
        overflow: scroll;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        }
        .indicator{
            width: 90%;
            height: 90%;
            position: fixed;
        }

<div class="journal">
    <div>text</div>
    <div>text</div>
    <div>text</div>
    <div>text</div>
    <div>text</div>
    <div class="indicator"></div>
</div>
```

Из-за того что у контейнера transfrom: rotateZ(0),  элемент indicator позиционируется относительно контейнера, а не окна (смена viewport) - это я все прекрасно понимаю.
Но проблема в том, что это чудо не работает в IE!! а мне надо, чтобы фиксированное позиционирование было относительно контейнера везде!
как это сделать?

Сама задача:
необходимо, чтобы блок в скролле оставался на месте, а текст двигался!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В ответ не пишу, потому что не проверял: https://habr.com/post/107183/

Comment: Суть не в том чтобы был поворот в IE, суть в том, чтобы была смена viewport, которая доступна при transform, perspective, filter

Comment: position: relative; http://htmlbook.ru/css/position Все дочерние элементы позиционируются относительно родителя (контейнера). А вот fixed как раз отменяет такую привязку.

Comment: Да! но мне нужен именно fixed и чтобы позиционирование было в блоке

Comment: Позиционирование внутри другого блока - это relative.Возможно пригодится использование absolute, но сильно сомневаюсь.

Comment: изменил вопрос и описал задачу конкретную